# Show results of select * from left join of two tables without using * (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to create a function which will show all the columns of this join but depending on a parameter, an extra column is added to the query. To show you how it works

This is the original query

```
SELECT * FROM bf_uom.V_BF_JOBS_STATUS Bj
left join bf_uom.bf_runs r
on bj.run_id = r.run_id
LEFT JOIN bf_uom.Bf_Document_Catalog Bdc
ON
  bf_uom.Bj.Document_Label = Bdc.Document_Label
left join bf_uom.bf_load_jobs lj
on lj.job_id=bj.job_id WHERE lj.job_id =:JOB_ID
```

But, if the input parameter is met, an extra column should be added to the query, like this

```
SELECT 'DOWNLOAD PDF' as "DOWNLOAD",* FROM bf_uom.V_BF_JOBS_STATUS Bj
left join bf_uom.bf_runs r
on bj.run_id = r.run_id
LEFT JOIN bf_uom.Bf_Document_Catalog Bdc
ON
  bf_uom.Bj.Document_Label = Bdc.Document_Label
left join bf_uom.bf_load_jobs lj
on lj.job_id=bj.job_id WHERE lj.job_id =:JOB_ID
```

This of course doesn't work, I tried with adding tables.* instead of *, but it still doesn't show the same number of columns as SELECT *.

How to solve this without typing the names of all columns that should be in the SELECT statement?

Comment: 'DOWNLOAD PDF' as "DOWNLOAD", bj.*, r.* 
when adding a column you must use the aliases of the referenced tables. (at least with ORACLE)

Comment: A single `*` may not be combined with anything else in the SELECT clause.

Comment: You'll get a mess of columns in case of `*` because the same column will be present multiple times. At least it would be better to use `using` clause in the `join` to remove duplicated join columns (while you may still have some generic column like `name` or `description` which is different for different tables). And table structure cannot be different depending on the parameter value because statement parsing is done before any data is passed to the statement. Use `case` expression to conditionally calculate this column and **do not consume it** if it is empty

Answer (score 1):

> How to solve this without typing the names of all columns that should be in the SELECT statement?

And yet, that's **exactly** what you should be doing.

---

Anyway, if you insist on *bad practice*, then this is what works:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC                EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK            7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK            7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK            7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10
<snip>

15 rows selected.
```

This is what doesn't work:

```
SQL> select 'download pdf' as download, *
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno;
select 'download pdf' as download, *
                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

If you specify all tables (along with the asterisk), then it works but - once again - that's bad practice:

```
SQL> select 'download pdf' as download, d.*, e.*
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno;

DOWNLOAD         DEPTNO DNAME          LOC                EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
------------ ---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
download pdf         10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK            7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
download pdf         10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK            7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81       5000                    10
download pdf         10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK            7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10
<snip>

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

In your case, you'd

```
SELECT 'DOWNLOAD PDF' as "DOWNLOAD", bj.*, r.*, bdc.*
```